# ffmpeg -stream_loop not working for .flv files

Tags: ffmpeg

## Does not work

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.flv -i song.mp3 -t 163 Timetest.flv

## Does work

ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.mp4 -i song.mp3 -t 163 Timetest.flv

My question is: how can I get -stream_loop to work with flv

Right now my workaround is a conversion to mp4

Rather not do that

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv out.mp4
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Share full logs.

Comment: the output video only shows 1 loop of the 2 second flv video

Comment: By simply changing flv to mp4 stream_loop works

Comment: This is a bug. You may open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: @Jay Try `ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.flv -stream_loop -1 -i song.mp3 -t 163 Timetest.flv`

Comment: oh wow that's interesting looping the mp3 as well, I'll update later